# jQuery Dialog Chrome issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a jQuery dialog box. I am facing an issue in Chrome browser.

```
 $("#dialog").append('<p class="elms">This is step 1</p>');
```

I have written js code where in, I am appending new content to the dialog box that is opened up. But I have ajax request after the append statement.

```
jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",....
```

What it does on Chrome is that the dialog box does not reflect the "This is step 1 message".

But it only displays the final result returned by jquery.ajax.

In Firefox browser "This is step 1 message". is shown also followed by the result returned from jquery.ajax call.

How do i fix this issue?

Comment: How are you appending the ajax content to the dialog?

Comment: $("#dialog").append('<p class="elms">This is ajax</p>'); I want to overwrite the content during the process

Answer (score 1):

recall .dialog();

```
 $("#dialog").append('<p class="elms">This is step 1</p>');
 $("#dialog").dialog();
```

if doesn't work for you, try this:

```
 $("#dialog").append('<p class="elms">This is step 1</p>').dialog();
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/XAa4x/)

Comment: For the sake of testing.. I added a timeout of 5 seconds just before the ajax call. I was then able to track the desired message. But when the application. I do not want to add a timeout as this would delay the process completion. What other option do I have now.

Comment: A little piece of code cant help much. Add some more relevant code. sothat I can help you